# Highlight Formula Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am making an Event Manager with data in Column A60:A150 (Event Name) B60:b150(Start Date) and C60 to c150(End Date) D60 to D150(Place)
when i am entering data in cells it appears event name in calendar

i want if value in Column D60:D150 ABC the dates should higlight green or any color

[image: Event]

As per image Red Bull should highlight Green and AAA should be other color if that Event Station/Place is different.

[image: Event2]

i use this formula

> =D60:d150="ABC"

color green and select range B3:AF50 but it is only changing color of cell b3 not as per dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,$A$60:$D$150,4,FALSE) = "ABC"
```

This will take the value in the cell and try to find it in the Range A60:A150.  If it finds the value it will return the Station/Place.  Then it tests if that equals "ABC" and returns True if it does.

If VLOOKUP Fails to find a match or that match does not equal "ABC", it will return False.

[image]

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this is the correct formula.

Comment: @Scott Craner it is not doing anything

Comment: @JohnHascall You are correct.  I had someone come into my office and had to post.

Comment: @MuhammadKhurrumButt I misread the location of the data.  See edit

Comment: @Scott Craner i think it should check Same row D60 cuz value in cell A60 is Showing up in cell as per date

Comment: Did you try the new formula I edited?  The Event is the value in the calendar, and you are testing on the location, so the new formula works.